# Dart check uncompleted Future

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to check if a `Future<dynamic>` is not yet completed after 500 millis.

```
RaisedButton(
  onPressed: () async {

    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });

    dynamic responseBody;

    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
      print(responseBody == null); // always false, so it never null, even uncompleted
      // if (responseBody != null) {
      //   isLoading = false;
      // }
    });

    NetworkHelper n = NetworkHelper(queryFinalUrl);
    responseBody = await n.getData();
  },
)
```

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class NetworkHelper {
  NetworkHelper(this.url);

  final String url;
  Future getData() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(this.url);

    String responseBody = response.body;
    return jsonDecode(responseBody);
  }
}
```

I tried to check my `dynamic` is `null` and `responseBody == null` , but it seems never `null`.

**Update for details:**

OK, I have a loading indicator / loading spinner which will cover fullscreen using `Visibility()` which I need to display once I pressed the button. So you might noticed the code `isLoading` is the visibility `bool`. So my idea is , I want to add on another timer counter `Future.delayed` immediately once button is pressed, so that is counts for 500 millis, and if:

1. 500ms has finished, and `responseBody` is not received yet , continue display the loading indicator
2. 500ms has finished and `responseBody` is completed, dismiss the loading indicator

Let's say `responseBody` completed in 400ms, Loading indicator must persist for another 100ms before it can be dismissed

I hope this details is clear for you. :) Sorry for inconvenience.

Yes, I'm aware I need to put an `await` while waiting for fetching web data

I show the loading indicator by `setState()`

So to conclude, this is why I wanna check if a `Future<dynamic>` is completed or uncompleted

Comment: I would advise you to give us a more broad view of what you are trying to accomplish. This code by itself is not self explanatory. Check the question guidelines for help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi, I have update the details, sorry for inconvenience. :)

Comment: There is no way to tell from a `Future` whether it is already completed or not.  You would need to keep track of that yourself.

Comment: Alright, so I think the simplest solution is just `try-catch` it by `try` read content of `responseBody` and `catch` it error, to identify it is completed or not

Answer (score 0):

Your `responseBody == null` check never succeeds because you do:

```dart
responseBody = n.getData();
```

which unconditionally assigns `responseBody` a `Future`. `responseBody` therefore will always be assigned a `Future`, regardless of whether it's complete or not.  You instead could do:

```dart
responseBody = await n.getData();
```

which will assign `responseBody` the *value* of the `Future` only after the `Future` completes.

Alternatively, you could use [`Future.timeout`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Future/timeout.html):

```dart
NetworkHelper n = NetworkHelper(queryFinalUrl);
try {
  dynamic responseBody = await n.getData().timeout(Duration(milliseconds: 100));
  ...
} on TimeoutException {
  isLoading = false;
}
```

Comment: If the timeout behavior is expected behavior and not a failsafe, I'd prefer the use of the `onTimeout` parameter of the `timeout` method rather than relying on a thrown error with a try-catch for flow control.

Comment: Another point-out is that the `timeout` method will cause the result of the original future to get discarded if the timeout phase passes, which may not be what OP necessarily wants.

Comment: Hi, I have update the details, sorry for inconvenience. :)

Comment: If I understand your answer correctly , `Future.timeout` that you've suggested is to terminate the data fetching if it timeout, but I think that's not what I'm looking for :)

Comment: @elliotching So does the first half of my answer not work for you?  With `responseBody = await n.getData();`, are you still observing that `responseBody` is never `null`?

Comment: yes, it is never `null` , because it is telling `Instance of Future<dynamic>`, and i've honestly no idea how to compare `==` an Instance of `Future<dynamic>`

Comment: If `responseBody` is `Future<dynamic>`, it sounds like you didn't actually use `await`.  Is this your actual code?  Maybe post a minimal, complete, verifiable example that demonstrates your problem.